# Triton Inference Server with Python backend Streaming

Tags: python, streaming, nvidia, inference, tritonserver

I am using Triton Inference Server with python backend, at moment send single grpc request does anybody know how we can use the python backend with streaming, because I didn't find any example or anything related to streaming the documentation.

Comment: see: https://github.com/triton-inference-server/server/blob/main/docs/decoupled_models.md

Comment: any solutions to this?